# Layouts of cms page don`t work in magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, cms, 404

I want to stylize the cms page 404. Content added through the admin page. To override the layout I created a file `cms_index_noroute.xml` in  `app/design/frontend/mytheme/Magento_Cms/layout`. However, the page does not see this file, it does not apply. I tried to rename the file in `cms_noroute_index.xml`. But no result. But at the same time the file `default.xml` is used, and my 404 page it sees. But I need a separate file for this particular page.
File code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <css src="css/views/cms-styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="title" remove="true"/>
</body></page>
```

Could someone help me with this?
Thank you so much!

Comment: I have the exact same thing. I'm trying to use the cmx_index_index.xml layout handle inside the Magento_Cms module. It does not get loaded for some unknown reason.